# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Tags: java, jsp, jpa

e estado trabajando en un projecto web con jpa 2.1, resulta que tengo problemas con la persistencia, creo que hay componentes del pom o del persistence que no los correctos y son los correctos, uso la linea en un jsp:

```
<%
    ControlUsuario controlusuario = new ControlUsuario();
%>
```

la clase ControlUsuario es:

```
@Entity
public class ControlUsuario {

private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;
private List<Usuario> _Usuario;
@Id
private Usuario Usuario;

public ControlUsuario() {
    this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FEDERACION");
    this.em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
    this._Usuario = consultarUsuario();
    this.Usuario = new Usuario();
}

public List<Usuario> consultarUsuario() {
    String jpql = " select * from USUARIO";
    Query query = this.em.createQuery(jpql);
    List<Usuario> _Usuario = query.getResultList();
    return _Usuario;
}

public Usuario loginUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    for (int a = 0; a < _Usuario.size(); a++) {
        if (usuario.getIdUSUARIO() == _Usuario.get(a).getIdUSUARIO()
                && usuario.getUNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD() == _Usuario.get(a).getUNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD()) {
            System.out.println("logeo satisfactorio");
        } else {
            System.out.println("logeo no satisfactorio");
            usuario = null;
        }
    }
    return usuario;
}

public void crearUsuario() {
    try {
        this.em.getTransaction().begin();
        this.em.persist(Usuario);
        this.em.getTransaction().commit();
        this.Usuario = new Usuario();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public List<Usuario> get_Usuario() {
    return _Usuario;
}

public void set_Usuario(List<Usuario> _Usuario) {
    this._Usuario = _Usuario;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return Usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario Usuario) {
    this.Usuario = Usuario;
}

}
```

el error que obtengo al intentar correr es:

```
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet [jsp] lanzó una excepción
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1080)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:765)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at control.ControlUsuario.<init>(ControlUsuario.java:23)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:181)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

mi pom es:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>FEDERACION</groupId>
<artifactId>FEDERACION</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

y mi persistence es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="FEDERACION"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>control.ControlUsuario</class>
    <class>control.ControlServicio</class>
    <class>control.ControlServicio_has_Universidad</class>
    <class>control.ControlUniversidad</class>
    <class>model.Servicio</class>
    <class>model.SERVICIO_has_UNIVERSIDAD</class>
    <class>model.Universidad</class>
    <class>model.Usuario</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/federacion" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="Unired2018*" />
        <property
            name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
            value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

uso mysql 5, no se si sirva de algo

Comment: ¿Qué *container*/servidor J2EE usas?

Comment: tienes un indice en esa tabla ? , recuerda que debes de señalarlo

Comment: Un `NoSuchMethodError` es una cuestión de versiones de librerías; falla mucho antes de intentar acceder a la BD. En todo caso, esto es más un comentario que una respuesta, y no se deben usar respuestas para hacer comentarios o pedir aclaraciones.

Comment: Además, en el *entity* que muestras no defines ningún `index`, así que no es ése el que da problemas.

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en esto , estoy abierto a los concejos.

Comment: tiene eclipselink 2.5, java runtime 1.8 corresobre un apache tomcat 9

Comment: ¿Por qué mezclas eclipselink con hibernate? Las dos son implementaciones de JPA, usarás una o la otra pero no las dos. No es que vaya a dar problemas por si solo, pero es raro.

Comment: la verdad en el projecto si me interfiere, igual deje ek jsp a un lado y estoy usando xhtml, no es tan complejo como jsp

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi, resulta que para jpa 2.1 se necesita eclipselink 2.5, runtime java 1.8, y modificar el persistence agregando a las propiedades:

```
        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"
            value="2000" />
```

pero aun asi tengo otro error, es:

```
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet [jsp] lanzó una excepción
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:   java.util.List, at table: UNIVERSIDAD, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(_universidad)]
```